# button in jsp showing previous named page

Tags: jsp

hii i have created a home jsp page and i want it to be conected with two more pages that later i renmaed them after i renamed them the buttons do not work and it shows me this error :"HTTP Status 404 - /ismgroupX/template_XXXXXXX/about_ex1_8XXXXXXX.jsp" istead of about_ex2_8XXXXXXX.jsp that is the name .Does anybody knows why this is happening
here is the part where i add the buttons

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ include file="header_ex2_XXXXXXX.jsp" %>

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">XXXXXXX</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index_ex2_8XXXXXXX.jsp">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="register_ex2_XXXXXXX.jsp">Register</a></li>                  
                <li><a href="about_ex2_XXXXXXX.jsp">About</a></li>                  
            </ul>        
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

I copied the files with the path to make sure that the corect files are mentioned , seperatly the files open just fine i would also like to mention that my files are stored in Winscp if it has to do anything with that